# MacOS Ventura Date Format Broken

Tags: system-settings, internationalization, time, ventura

In System Settings, General, Language & Region, Date format, I choose year/month/day.

But Finder still shows dates in confusing month/day/year.

This was not a problem prior to updating macOS to Ventura. Is there a way to fix this (such as in Terminal)?

Answer (score -1):

This user tip from apple's forums may help

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250005846

Comment: Please include the relevant information here, rather than just giving a link. See: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)